# Unhandled promise rejection when using Native Modules from React Native after implementing native Toast module

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-toast

I'm trying to implement Toast by creating a module in React Native, but when I try to execute it in the JavaScript part, I receive this YellowBox:

```
Warning Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_modules.Toast.show')
```

The creation of the module

```java
package com.project-name.modules;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Toast";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void show(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Registering the module

```java
package com.project-name;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.project-name.modules.ToastModule;

public class ToastPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new ToastModule(reactContext));
    return modules;
  }
}
```

And then, I added this to my `MainApplication.java`

```java
...
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.project-name.ToastPackage;
...
protected List getPackages() {
  return Arrays.asList(
    new MainReactPackage(),
    new ToastPackage()
  );
}
```

Now, in the JavaScript part, I created a file in `utils/modules.js`:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const { Toast } = NativeModules

export { Toast }
```

Which I then, in my component, I call

```js
import { Toast } from '../../utils/modules'
...
Toast.show('Foo!')
...
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? I followed the official tutorial in the website, yet, this warning message appears.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app is rebuilt after adding the Android bridging code.
Also, your 'show' method interface has an extra (unused) duration parameter that is not mentioned when calling the method from React-Native.